# Weak derivative of one parameter group and the domain of its generator

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $U(t)=\exp(i t A)$ be a one parameter group generated by self-adjoint (unbounded) operator A. It is well-known that if
$$
 \lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac{U(t)\psi-\psi}{t}
$$
exists then $\psi$ belongs to the domain of $A$ (see e.g. Reed and Simon 'Methods of Modern Mathematical Physics I', theorem VIII.7).

I would like to replace the condition with the following one:
$$
 \forall_{\phi\in\mathcal{H}}\lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac{(\phi|U(t)\psi-\psi)}{t}
~~~~~~\textrm{and}~~~~~
 \forall_{\phi\in\mathcal{H}} \lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac{(\phi|U(t)\psi+U(-t)\psi-2\psi)}{t^2}
$$
exist. Does it imply that $\psi$ is in the domain of $A$?

Intuitively the first condition guarantees the existence of the weak derivative, and the second one tells us that the norm is continuous. Am I right?

Note that for $\psi \in \operatorname{Dom}(A)$ we have
$$
 \forall_{\phi\in\mathcal{H}}\lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac{(\phi|U(t)\psi-\psi)}{t}=(\phi|A\psi)
~~~~~~\textrm{and}~~~~~
 \lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac{(\psi|U(t)\psi+U(-t)\psi-2\psi)}{t^2}=(A\psi,A\psi).
$$

Comment: your limit shoudl it be $ (\phi | i \frac{dA}{dt}|\phi ) $

Comment: For all $\psi\in Dom(A)$ we have $\lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac{U(t)\psi-\psi}{t} = i A \psi$. I'm interested in reverse statement i.e. I want to find a useful condition which guarantees that $\psi$ is in the domain of $A$.

Comment: Is $H$ supposed to be the same as $A$?

Comment: A=H. I've corrected the the typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Section 2.1 of A. Pazy's book *Semigroups of Linear Operators and Applications to 
Partial Differential Equations* is called "Weak equals strong". There he shows that the 
weak generator of a $C_0$ semigroup is the same as the strong generator.

Granted he works with semigroups, not groups, over a real (not complex) Banach space
 but you may want to investigate his techniques. It may well be that the existence of 
the weak limit $$w- \lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac{U(t)\psi-\psi}{t}$$ is enough to give 
$\psi\in \mbox{Dom}(A)$.